# Keep user in Activity

Tags: android, android-studio

I was creating an app then a question come out:
how can i keep user in activity?
I've put two editTexts with input of int.
i want user be kept in activity until he/she puts valid numbers in edittexts.
any ideas?

Comment: i added an if for the situation that an input is invalid:if(aN==0){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"all can't be zero",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            startActivity(returnToInputActivity);
        }

Comment: you question is vague, are you trying to say that the user cannot close the app unless correct inputs are inputted by user in edit textbox or they cant leave current activity to go on another unless correct inputs are inputted by user ?

Comment: yes, that's what i want

Comment: ok got it, now show us what you tried so far , if you haven't tell us that too.

Comment: in apps like Instagram app for example in log page. when user puts a wrong phone number , after pressing login button a red text shows up and says "your phone number is invalid" and keeps user in page instead of moving him to the next activity

Comment: in insta they have a if condition, if it passes then user is send to next activity otherwise nothing happens... so jus use a if condtion

Comment: ok got it will post the answer, one more thing see now I understand you question because you elaborated in the comments make sure next time you do it in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is very simple all you need to do is get the string values from the edit text box and have a condition in your setonclicklistener that checks the strings if they match to a certain value, if yes the intent from current activity will take you to next if not it will show an error on the edit text box (by using `.setError()`) and return.

**Here is the Java Class Code:**

```
package com.example.text_to_speech;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class ActivityA extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity);

        EditText editText1,editText2;
        Button button;


        editText1=findViewById(R.id.ed1);
        editText2=findViewById(R.id.ed2);

        button=findViewById(R.id.check_input);

            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(!editText1.getText().toString().equals("Don"))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(ActivityA.this, "You Can't Leave this Activity, Input Correct Fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        editText1.setError("Input Correct values");
                        return;
                    }
                    if(!editText1.getText().toString().equals("Tom"))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(ActivityA.this, "You Can't Leave this Activity, Input Correct Fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        editText2.setError("Input Correct values");
                        return;
                    }
                    Intent intent=new Intent(ActivityA.this,MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

**XML Code:**

<RelativeLayout

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ActivityA">


    <EditText
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/ed1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:hint="Input Data Here"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/ed1"
        android:id="@+id/ed2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:hint="Input Data Here"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/ed2"
        android:id="@+id/check_input"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:text="Go to Next Activity"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Output:

[image: Output of Above Code]

Comment: no problem :)..